# reference type parameter question

Tags: c#, .net

I learnt the reference type parameter passing is just a copy of the reference. If you set the passed in refernece parameter point to another object inside the called method, the orginal reference will not change.

I have a test method to test the reference type parameter passing. A `refTest(SystemSwEvent systemSwEvent)` method is called from that test method with a valid SystemSwEvent type object. Inside the `refTest()` method, the `processEvScanDataAvailable(EvScanDataAvaialble systemSwEvent)` method is called. Inside the `processEvScanDataAvailable(EvScanDataAvaialble systemSwEvent)` method, I set the passed in reference parameter to `null`. I expect the parameter in `refTest()` should not be changed. But that is not true. It will be changed  to null **momentarily**. why?[image]

[image]

Comment: I just filed a connect issue on this, if you want to vote for it: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/662071/debugger-showing-improper-information-in-mouse-hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why?

I suspect this is a debugger issue, and not representative of what's actually occurring inside the CLR.

Try using different variable names for your arguments, and this behavior will go away.

Answer (score 4):

The debugger recognizes the name *in the current context* and shows the value. *It's just a coincidence* that you pointed your cursor at a place that actually triggered the currently executing method (the current context).

Also note you can use the Call Stack tool to inspect the parameters of caller methods.

Answer (score 0):

Object references are by default (if you don't qualify them with `ref` or `out`) passed *by value*, so the method is receiving a copy of the object reference - setting that copy to `null` doesn't change the original object reference, so what you claim to see is impossible and most likely you are just misinterpreting what you see in the debugger.

Comment: Reference types are always passed by reference, regardless of ref or out.

Comment: @Tejs: But the references themselves are _passed by value_.

Comment: @Tejs: The object reference **itself** is passed by value, note that I said reference and not object.

Comment: what's your mean about "misinterpreting"? yes, I cannot believe what I see but it is always like that in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger is getting confused because your parameter and variable have the same name. If you change the name of your parameter, you will notice that that debugger no longer gives information about the variable being *passed into* the method, but only gives information on the variable *inside* the method.

Simply change the name of that parameter, and you will no longer have this issue.